# Formatting a predefined Date value to ISO format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting, iso8601

I need to send a date value to the server in ISO Format `"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]"` I don't need the time details so I am setting them as zero.

For that I am using the below code

```
var today = new Date();
var todayWithTimeAsZero = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
```

I get `todayWithTimeAsZero` as `Tue Jul 25 2017 22:06:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Now how do I convert this date into an ISO format. I researched everywhere but no luck.

I tried `var day = todayWithTimeAsZero.toISOString();` but this creates a new date object with the time values populated like so `2017-07-24T18:30:00.000Z`. Also I have momentjs in my project may be in some way I can use that.

Comment: What is wrong with todayWithTimeAsZero.toISOString();?

Comment: It is updating the zeroes with the new time values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `moment.js` you can get the current date as UTC, then set the time values to zero and get the ISO string:

```
moment() // current date
.utc() // convert to UTC
.hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0) // set time values to zero
.toISOString() // format to ISO8601
```

The value of the formatted string is `2017-07-25T00:00:00.000Z`.

---

You can also use the `setUTCxxx` methods of `Date`:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setUTCHours(0);
today.setUTCMinutes(0);
today.setUTCSeconds(0);
today.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
```

`today.toISOString()` will be `2017-07-25T00:00:00.000Z`.

Comment: You can zero the time on one go: `today.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Date then zero the UTC time and get just the date, it will be a different date from the local date for the period of the timezone offset. For someone in UTC+1000 the UTC date is yesterday until 10:00. For users who are UTC-0600 it will be "tomorrow" after 18:00 (6 pm).

Anyway, without any library you can do:

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(d.toISOString());
```